# Cloning an image, pixel by pixel

Tags: android, pixel, android-bitmap

I want to create an app that reads an image, pixel by pixel, and use this information to build a clone image. For that I am using 2 ImageViews, one has an artistic picture and the other has an empty picture( only white background ).

When I click the button to start the image cloning, I get this message:

> Unfortunately, the app has stopped

I tried several changes suggested in several posts but I could not sort out this problem.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cloneAnImagePixelByPixel();
    }

    public void cloneAnImagePixelByPixel()
    {

            final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    ImageView artimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.art);
                    ImageView emptyimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.emptyim);

                    Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable) artimg.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) emptyimg.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                    int img_height = bitmap1.getHeight();
                    int img_width = bitmap1.getWidth();

                    for (int i = 0; i < img_height; i++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < img_width; k++)
                        {
                            int pixel = bitmap1.getPixel(i, k);

                            int a = Color.alpha(pixel);
                            int r = Color.red(pixel);
                            int g = Color.green(pixel);
                            int b = Color.blue(pixel);

                            bitmap2.setPixel(i, k, Color.argb(a,r,g,b));

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

And here is xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mypc.creatingacloneimagefrompixels.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/art"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sandart"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="125dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="57dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emptyim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="125dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="205dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/art" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLONE IMAGE"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="122dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="380dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="83dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/emptyim" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Event Log is here:

```
28-Jul-17
10:18 AM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

10:18 AM    Gradle build finished in 11s 988ms

10:38 AM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

10:38 AM    Gradle build finished in 4s 956ms

10:38 AM    ADB rejected shell command (cat /proc/2560/stat): closed

The gradle console is here:

    Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\EASYPC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout102Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoCore222Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestEspressoEspressoIdlingResource222Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestExposedInstrumentationApiPublish05Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRules05Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestRunner05Library
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.717 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\EASYPC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout102Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkManifestChangesDebug
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDependencyCheckerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsAndResourcesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
:app:transformClassesEnhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDebug
:app:incrementalDebugTasks
:app:preColdswapDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug
:app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug
:app:packageDebug
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 11.919 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\EASYPC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout102Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2600Alpha1Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkManifestChangesDebug
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDependencyCheckerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsAndResourcesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesEnhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugTasks UP-TO-DATE
:app:preColdswapDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.89 secs
```

The Android Monitor is here:

```
07-28 10:38:46.196 2560-2560/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10080: Read-only file system
07-28 10:38:46.196 2560-2560/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
07-28 10:38:46.197 2560-2560/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-28 10:38:46.211 2560-2570/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
07-28 10:38:46.211 2560-2570/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
07-28 10:38:46.293 2560-2560/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-28 10:38:46.334 2560-2560/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-28 10:38:46.426 2560-2583/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                 [ 07-28 10:38:46.427  2560: 2560 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3ee71f0, tid 2560


                                                 [ 07-28 10:38:46.428  2560: 2560 W/         ]
                                                 Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 
07-28 10:38:46.428 2560-2560/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
07-28 10:38:46.451 2560-2583/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-28 10:38:46.452 2560-2583/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-28 10:38:46.460 2560-2583/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xb3eb8940: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
07-28 10:38:46.464 2560-2583/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb3eb8940: ver 2 0
07-28 10:38:46.467 2560-2583/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
07-28 10:38:46.500 2560-2583/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb3eb8940: ver 2 0
07-28 10:38:46.555 2560-2560/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
07-28 10:38:51.028 2560-2560/com.example.easypc.creatingacloneimagefrompixels D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-28 10:38:51.030 2560-2560/com.example.easypc.creatingacloneimagefrompixels E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                Process: com.example.easypc.creatingacloneimagefrompixels, PID: 2560
                                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                                                    at android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixel(Bitmap.java:1420)
                                                                                                    at com.example.easypc.creatingacloneimagefrompixels.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Logcat please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: It's a bit difficult to identify the problem without your StackTrace. Please update your question.

Comment: Hi Vinit
Thank you for your comment.
I already added the Gradle Console, the Event Log and the Android Monitor contents.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that `bitmap2` is not mutable. You can create a mutable Bitmap by use `Bitmap.copy()` with `isMutable` set to true or using `Bitmap.create(width,height,config)`. You can also load a mutable Bitmap by setting `inMutable` to true in BitmapFactory.Options using `BitmapFactory`

Comment: Hi @cwbowron

I did the change in the code ( see below ) but the app still does not work. i am not sure if the path of the image in BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/images/empty.png",options); is correct. The path in relation to the project name is this: F:\Android-Projects\CreatingACloneImageFromPixels\app\images\empty.png. I am assuming that the "app" folder is the root of the application.

Comment: ( continuation )
The code changes are between the two line plus the commented line above:

          `code` 
//Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) emptyimg.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inMutable=true;
                    Bitmap outputBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/images/empty.png",options);
                    emptyimg.setImageBitmap(outputBitmap);
                    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 `code`

Comment: ( continuation )
Did I make the correct declarations and used the right parameters ?